# converting sqlite to postgres

Tags: sqlite, postgresql

I have another sqlite script that I need to convert to postgres. Take a gander if you can assist :)

```
SELECT count(*), strftime('%H', sentdate) as hour FROM latency l, contacts me 
   WHERE l.lat < 1 and datetime(sentdate) > datetime('2009-01-01') and datetime(sentdate)       
       < datetime('2011-02-01') and (me.id = l.replyuid or me.id = l.senduid) 
   GROUP BY hour ORDER BY hour asc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that sentdate is a date/timestamp field then this ought to work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
    date_part('hour', sentdate ) AS hour
FROM latency l,
    contacts me
WHERE l.lat < 1
    AND date_trunc ('day', sentdate) > DATE ( '2009-01-01' )
    AND date_trunc ('day', sentdate) < DATE ( '2011-02-01' )
    AND ( me.id = l.replyuid
        OR me.id = l.senduid )
GROUP BY date_part('hour', sentdate )
ORDER BY hour ASC;
```

Comment: If I were writing this query, I might try to make this an inner join (instead of comma join), and since there's an `or` in the join conditiion, I'd express that as a union, same query, but maybe more idiomatic sql.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy - true enough. I very much prefer ANSI joins, however I was trying not to deviate too far from the original query...